# Uniform convergence of $f_n (x) = \frac{x}{nx+1}, x\in(0,1).$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm checking the convergence of the function $f_n (x) = \frac{x}{nx+1}, x\in(0,1).$

So it seems that converges point-wise to $0$, and this could be shown by taking $N=\displaystyle\frac{x-\epsilon}{x\epsilon}$, because then if $n>N$ follows $\displaystyle \left|\frac{x}{nx+1} \right|< \frac{x}{\frac{x-\epsilon}{x\epsilon}x+1} = \frac{x}{\frac{x-\epsilon}{\epsilon}+1}=\frac{x}{\frac{x-\epsilon+\epsilon}{\epsilon}}=\frac{x\epsilon}{x}=\epsilon.$

(The value of $N$ was found taking $\frac{x}{nx+1}<\epsilon$ and moving from there).

Now since the $N$ depends of $x$ I could affirm that the series of function does not converges uniformly, however the $\sup$ criterion says otherwise:

$\sup_{x\in(0,1)}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\sup_{x\in(0,1)}\left|\frac{x}{nx+1}-0\right|=\sup_{x\in(0,1)}\left|\frac{x}{nx+1}\right|=\frac{1}{n+1}\to 0$ if $n\to+\infty$.

Is this a contradiction?

Comment: No, the uniform convergence implies the pointwise convergence. The fact that $N$ depends of $x$ can be thus solved by taking the larger $N$ possible, this is possible because of the uniform convergence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The particular $N$ you got is not the best. There could be some other $N$  not depending on $x$. Your last argument is correct and it **proves** that $f_n \to 0$ uniformly.

Comment: Can we use the fact that $0 \leq \frac{x}{nx+1} \leq \frac{x}{nx}=\frac{1}{n}$ for all $x \in (0,1)$ and so $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{x \in (0,1)} \frac{x}{nx+1}=0$ by squeeze theorem? Thanks.

Comment: @Dunkelheit You surely can.